# Calling R using the bash exec command

Tags: linux, r, bash

I'm using the `exec` command to call `R`, but I don't understand how to handle arguments. For example the following line calls `R` and loads a script:

```
exec('/bin/R --vanilla < /home/docs/R/plotTemplate.R');
```

Then I want to set the directory and to call a function in the `R` script. The folder's name is `randomNumber` so I need to somehow either pass that value to the script and set the directory within the R script or to pass it as an argument to the script.

```
exec("setwd(/home/reports/randomNumber/")
```

I can't figure out how to stitch these lines together so that it is one exec command. A better approach might be to write a `bash` script but I'm also not clear on how to do this either.

Comment: so is the code you're showing 'R' code? And per your comments to answer below, why do you think you need `exec`? Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to write an *R script* and call that with the `Rscript` front-end which is designed with these tasks in mind.

If you on an OS with an x in its name, you can also try [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) for R scripting.

Comment: I updated my question; I am trying to pass one argument in to my script, ideally using the `exec` command. I realize I could have just called the `R script` the way that I phrased it previously without passing an argument in.

Comment: You *still* want Rscript and look at the other questions on SO to pick up command-line arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk that pointed me in the right direction and I got it to work.